# Change colorscheme based on terminal colours

Tags: macos, vim, zsh, iterm2, iterm

I use iTerm, zsh and vim.

When my terminal is using the *Solarized Light* profile I want my vimrc to

```
color solarized
set background=light
```

but when I am using *Lucario-ish* I want my vimrc to

```
color lucario
set background=dark
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

I've been unable to find out if there's a way to detect the current profile in either zsh or vim, maybe I will have to set up my profiles to set some environment variable when they are being used.

I could detect this environment variable in vim,

```
if $PROFILE == "solarized"
  color solarized
  set background=light
else
  ...
```

Is there a way to do it without me having to change my profiles or write anything outside of my vimrc?

Can I do this just by changing my vimrc?

Comment: how about change the `~/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh`, and set the environment variable there instead of setting that in the profile.

Comment: @sel-fish how do I check the profile from a script though?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to make a list of colors and another with corresponding backgrounds:

```
let mycolors = ["solarized","lucario"]
let mybgs = ["light","dark"]
```

then traverse the first list, comparing its values with $PROFILE:

```
let j=0
for i in mycolors      
  if $PROFILE == mycolors[j]                                                    
    execute "colorscheme ".mycolors[j]                                        
    execute "set background=".mybgs[j]                                   
    break                                                                   
  endif
  let j+=1                                                                
endfor
```

Comment: But my question is how I can do this w/o setting environment variables manually